# DEBUG log rotation in JAVA

Tags: java, debugging, logging, rotation, slf4j

In a production environnement (for example) we often use INFO log level because with DEBUG log the size become quickly huge.

I know that's it's possible with SLJ4J or LOG4J to configure log rotation to split files etc.
But most of the time, we only need DEBUG logs when an exception appear, so we can have more information (HTTP Request logs for example).

I'm wondering if it's possible to keep only (for example) 1 minute of DEBUG log and save it if an exception appear. (Main log file is always on level INFO)
For example, when a HttpRequestException occurs, we have a file saved with 1 Minute of DEBUG log HttpRequestException-10-02-2015-10:28:50.log in a specific folder

So we can easily see all exceptions in this folder

```
/Exceptions/
   - HttpRequestException-10-02-2015-10:28:50.log
   - NullPointerException-10-02-2015-10:29:51.log
   - IOException-10-02-2015-11:29:51.log
```

So... is it possible to do it with a tool like slf4j ?
And is DEBUG logging a huge performance problem on a production server?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution.
I use **cyclicBufferTracker** to tell appender to use the last x lines once trigerred
And I can use the **evaluator** attribute to configure the trigger (default trigger is when an ERROR occurs)

Email is ok for me, but if someone want to put it in files instead of email I think you can create a custom Appender instead of SMTPAppender

Like on this page : http://jira.qos.ch/browse/LOGBACK-207

Here is the actual code : (You will need javax.activation and javax.mail if you use email implementation) and if you use gmail like me you will need to allow low security app in gmail settings : [Gmail less secure apps](https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps)

```xml
<appender name="EMAIL" class="ch.qos.logback.classic.net.SMTPAppender">
   <smtpHost>smtp.gmail.com</smtpHost>
   <smtpPort>587</smtpPort>
   <asynchronousSending>false</asynchronousSending>
   <STARTTLS>true</STARTTLS>
   <username>GoogleUsername</username>
   <password>mypassword</password>
   <to>GoogleUsername@gmail.com</to>
   <from>GoogleUsername@gmail.com</from>
   <subject>Exception Alert</subject>
   <layout class="ch.qos.logback.classic.PatternLayout">
      <pattern>%date - %message%n</pattern>
   </layout>
   <cyclicBufferTracker class="ch.qos.logback.core.spi.CyclicBufferTracker">
      <bufferSize>50</bufferSize>
   </cyclicBufferTracker>
</appender>
```

Hope it will help